# Why use the AWS CloudFormation Template generator if the template it creates is invalid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to automate my server setup process so I finally looked into using CloudFormation. I started the CloudFormation Template service so that it could introspect my current setup (in account A) and generate a template for me to use in a new account (account B). I'm building the template from Oregon and trying to run it in Oregon. Full template is here (real IPs, account numbers and passwords have been scrubbed): https://gist.github.com/cannikin/9801aa3451d538be1689

When I try to start the stack based on that template I get 15 CREATE_FAILED events and then the whole thing rolls back. Looking at some of the messages I see a lot of `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress | egress3 | Encountered unsupported property CidrIP` If I look up `egress3` in the template:

```
"egress3": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupId": {
      "Ref": "sgweb"
    },
    "IpProtocol": "-1",
    "CidrIP": "0.0.0.0/0"
  }
}
```

That seems to be a pretty simple rule: allow outbound connections to any IP. I didn't even create that rule, it's just the default outbound rule for new security groups (inbound rules are the ones are where you want to limit to certain IP addresses).

How is that invalid, ESPECIALLY when it was created by their own template generator? Am I not supposed to include egress rules?

I see my account A account number in there a couple of times (123456789), maybe that needs to be swapped to the account B account number?

Answer (score 2):

It's invalid because you have a syntax error. `"CidrIP"` should be `"CidrIp"` . For example https://gist.github.com/cannikin/9801aa3451d538be1689#file-cloudformation-template-L460

I would recommend you to run a "test" first using `aws cli`. For example:

`aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://foo.json`

Answer (score 0):

Even if the validate test succeeds, your cloudformation templates could always fail for reasons unaticipated. The aws resources sometimes have tight dependencies that will only come to surface when you deploy them. Validate template operation checks for only template syntax, functions validations to some extent. But it doesn't always have full visibility over runtime resources. The best we could try is make sure the template dependency is taken care of according to aws documentation.